# How can I get list of window's tabs in react web app with chrome extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

In chrome extension, I am able to get all window tabs in popup.html

But i am unaware about how to communicate with chrome extension so that i get all tabs in react index page. Please provide details with code. Thanks in Advance.